# Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first. After Removal

Tags: wpf, vb.net

First off here is what i am trying to do:  I need to dynamically reverse the order of the items in one stack panel and add them in the reverse order in a second.  Here is the code that i am using:

```
 Dim cp As ContentPresenter = TryCast(Utilities.GetDescendantFromName(TitleLegend, "ContentPresenter"), ContentPresenter)
        If cp IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim sp As StackPanel = TryCast(cp.Content, StackPanel)
            If sp IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim nsp As New StackPanel() With {.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical}
                Dim count As Integer = sp.Children.Count
                For i As Integer = count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    Dim cc As ContentControl = TryCast(sp.Children(i), ContentControl)
                    If cc IsNot Nothing Then
                        sp.Children.Remove(cc)
                        nsp.Children.Add(cc)
                    End If
                Next
                cp.Content = Nothing
                cp.Content = nsp
            End If
        End If
```

it runs through this code fine but right before the User Control loads i receive the error.  I have looked around here and the solution that seems to work is removing the child from the first collection which i already do.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution that i used to solve my problem in case anyone else runs into this situation

```
  Dim cp As ContentPresenter = TryCast(Utilities.GetDescendantFromName(TitleLegend, "ContentPresenter"), ContentPresenter)
        If cp IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim sp As StackPanel = TryCast(cp.Content, StackPanel)

            If sp IsNot Nothing Then
                If tempList Is Nothing Then
                    tempList = New List(Of ContentControl)
                End If
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(Function()
                                                      Dim count As Integer = sp.Children.Count
                                                      For i As Integer = count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                                                          Dim cc As ContentControl = TryCast(sp.Children(i), ContentControl)
                                                          sp.Children.Remove(TryCast(sp.Children(i), ContentControl))
                                                          If cc IsNot Nothing Then
                                                              tempList.Add(cc)
                                                          End If
                                                      Next

                                                      For i As Integer = count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                                                          Dim cc As ContentControl = TryCast(tempList(0), ContentControl)
                                                          tempList.Remove(TryCast(tempList(0), ContentControl))
                                                          If cc IsNot Nothing Then
                                                              sp.Children.Add(cc)
                                                          End If
                                                      Next

                                                  End Function), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, Nothing)
            End If
        End If
```